# How to get all projects on a dashboard in multiple columns?

Tags: sonarqube

We have a TV displaying our Sonar stats for all our projects, but now that we have 20+ projects, and it doesn't all fit in the screen.  We would like our dashboard to look like this (so all the projects fit on one screen):

```
+----------+----------+  +----------+----------+
|   Name   | Coverage |  |   Name   | Coverage |
+----------+----------+  +----------+----------+
| Project1 |       45 |  | Project5 |       18 |
| Project2 |       15 |  | Project6 |       22 |
| Project3 |       45 |  | Project7 |       45 |
| Project4 |       15 |  | Project8 |       22 |
+----------+----------+  +----------+----------+
```

Is this possible?  Right now we are using the widget "Measure Filter as List", so that we don't have to hard-code the project names into a widget.  As new projects get added to Sonar, we don't have to manually add them to any dashboard... they should automatically get added.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible. But you can implement your own widget that displays the list of project using a "fluid" layout in order to meet your needs.

See our [sample plugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/sonar-reference-plugin) to learn how to write your own plugin that adds a widget in SonarQube.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  That's what I thought the answer would be.  I'll look into that link.

Comment: Can you provide how we can write custom widget that can access list of projects? The sample code for widgets in github is only about ptoject level widget